# Dropdown List in Excel to Show Data from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table of data, with various months in various columns, each row has a unique identifier (in this instance, a name).

Is there a way I can, in another sheet, have a drop down box so I can choose a date and the sheet then returns all entries from the data with those dates?

Here's a link to a very basic version of the type of data I'm working with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LgTKxXuQ9hdq-ruJWcto7A002ks4R2koGx0vtiHZHXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, there is way to do that. Do you have tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I've spent all morning. I tried initially pivot table but I couldn't get the result I was after.

Comment: Share some sample data and expected output. It would be better if you can share a sample excel file. Some input and output.

Comment: Does it need to be in a separate sheet?  If not i think a filter on top of the table should do the trick.

Comment: @Wujaszkun a filter won't work. The dates are in different columns.

Comment: @harun24hr just included a link to a basic spreadsheet for you to see what I mean https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LgTKxXuQ9hdq-ruJWcto7A002ks4R2koGx0vtiHZHXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please share some sample input data and the expected output?

Comment: @Karpak please see the link in the main question and the link in the above comment

Comment: @danjswade I am not understanding, what output you want.

Comment: Both link shows the same excel. it doesn't explain what exactly you want with sample.

Comment: apologies, updated now with a hand-typed second tab to show what I'd like to happen

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this little code:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastRow, targetCell, sourceRng, cell, nameRng, startRng, ddownCell As Range

Set ddownCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:O10")
Set nameRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10")
Set startRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B10")
Set targetCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5")

If Not Application.Intersect(ddownCell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

With Worksheets("Sheet2")                               '
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    '
    If lastRow > 3 Then                                 'clears the content of previous search
        .Range("A5:B" & lastRow).ClearContents          '
    End If                                              '
End With                                                '

For Each cell In sourceRng
    If cell.Value = ddownCell.Value Then
         targetCell.Value = nameRng.Rows(cell.Row - 1).Value
         targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = startRng.Rows(cell.Row - 1).Value
         Set targetCell = targetCell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If

Next cell
End If
End Sub
```

The sheet names and cell ranges are adjusted to the sample you have posted and need to  be adjusted.

This code should be pasted into the Sheet2 in VBA editor.